# custom field in the IPN of paypal adaptive payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented  Adaptive Payment in my website. First It was Standard Payment so in that i was passing a `custom` parameter in the form and i was getting it in IPN. But i am unable to find how to pass this parameter in  Adaptive Payment.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[Edit]**

As per @jackvsworld suggests in PayPal Adaptive use parameter as `ipnNotificationUrl`.

I did this by passing into `GET` parameters of `notify_url`

For e.g. `http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?param_1=value&param_2=value`

Comment: I considered using the cancel and return URLs, because they are required yet unused for many operations. Your solution is way better though. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @jimy to use the querystring, but in PayPal Adaptive the parameter is **not** `notify_url`.

For PayPal Adaptive use the `ipnNotificationUrl` field of the Pay or Preapproval request

Source: [Identifying Your IPN Listener to PayPal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNSetup)