# Paypal Adaptive Payment API Custom Variable IPN Return

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to do Adaptive Payment API with a IPN and have been find that with the sandbox environment I'm not getting back payer's address or custom variables.  I've seen this in another post with custom variable but is this the case when using the Adaptive payment API.  When I sent a test IPN I can do numerous variables but when checking out through the sandbox I don't get the payer's address.  Which I would like.  Can I not get the payers Address or Custom variable back from Adaptive API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the issue or solution.  Basically the IPN for the API is different then the IPN for the instant payment.  You can get a custom variable through the GET method but make sure you use parse the IPN different or you won't get it.

The parsing information is here:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/adaptive-payments-api/php-technique-parsing-adaptive-payment-ipn-posts?page=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1

and sending a custom variable through is here:
[custom field in the IPN of paypal adaptive payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028642/custom-field-in-the-ipn-of-paypal-adaptive-payment)

Although apparently I have been told if you use adaptive payments you cannot get back the billing address information of the customer.