# Custom field is not posted from IPN paypal adaptive

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have two problem regarding paypal adaptive api.
**Problem 1: Am not getting IPN POST from Paypal Sandbox**

I set `ipn_notification_url` in the `pay` api call and the request is completed successfully. Payment is completed but the notification is not received from paypal sandbox.

When i try IPN simulator i can able to get POST Values but i'm not sure why it is not working for sandbox payment completion.

I haven't set any notification URL in Testing account Profile. PayPal says it is completely okay even if we not set Notification URL in Profile Instead we can specify in API call.
[REFERENCE](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/)

```
Note: The IPN message will always be sent to your notification URL unless receiving IPNs have been disabled. Even though you have not enabled receiving IPN messages in your Profile or you have reset your preference by turning off IPN messages, PayPal still sends IPN messages to the notification URL you specify for a specific payment. IPN messages not sent because you disabled the preference in your Profile will appear in the IPN history when you enable receiving IPNs. After they appear in the history, you can choose whether or not to resend them.
```

Why i couldn't get POST FROM IPN SERVICE?

**Problem 2: Am not getting custom field from IPN if set the Notification URL in Testing Profile Setting**

If i set the Notification URL in Testing Profile am getting the POST from IPN but it does not contain the `custom` field which i set from `PAY` Request. So i couldn't make my order as complete. I got an work around answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028642/custom-field-in-the-ipn-of-paypal-adaptive-payment). But it is not possible in my case as the notification URL is static from Testing Profile.

If it is dynamic then i'll try to use the $_GET to place my order ID in `ipn_notification_url` itself and then i'll get it in response.

But it is not even sending Any POST as i stated it as my first problem.

What can i do with this situation? Is Problem 1 is a temporary problem? Will it work in live?

Is there any solution to this?

Am trying to do this in woocommerce order.
Any help or reference is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you set an IPN notification URL in your profile anyway to test? I would check the IPN history to see if it is being sent (under history), you can also check the raw POST to see if custom is being set.

Comment: Hi thanks for the heads up. I checked in Profile IPN history, the IPN is sent. I even resent it. BUt i couldn't get the `custom` field in the raw `POST`. I debugged it by saving the `POST` values and i checked in there the `custom` value is empty.

Comment: Start trouble shooting the script that POSTS the custom field to Paypal then sounds like its not being sent properly.